# CSS only for first matching element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

I have multiple repeating div sections containing paragraphs and I want to apply specific CSS only on the first matching paragraph inside the div.

```css
div.example1 p.special~p.special {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Top Paragraph</p>
<div class='top'>

  <div class="example1">
    <p class="special">This is paragraph 1 and it should be green and bold</p>
  </div>

  <div class="example1">
    <p class="special">This is paragraph 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="example1">
    <p class="special">This is paragraph 3</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is the [link -](https://codepen.io/devesh-singh-the-flexboxer/pen/JjybXgg)

Answer (score 2):

**The problem**
With the second css selector you are modifying all p tags that come after a p tag that are inside a div with the class of example1

**The solution**
Instead of targeting the first p tag, target the first .example1 div instead by doing to following:

```css
.example1:first-of-type .special {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Top Paragraph</p>
<div class='top'>

  <div class="example1">
    <p class="special">This is paragraph 1 and it should be green and bold</p>
  </div>

  <div class="example1">
    <p class="special">This is paragraph 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="example1">
    <p class="special">This is paragraph 3</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Side note** try keeping your css selectors as short as possible and strate to the point. avoid doing things like `div.class` but instead use `.class`

Comment: Your answer is right, but I'd consider giving a reason why it's considered good practice to keep selectors "flat" and not over-qualify them by adding too much specificity.

Comment: @UncaugthTypeError its good practice because when doing it like div.class you raise the specificity. Which can cause countless of hours trying to override it, this may not make sense in a small project but when scaling things it really gets complicated and hard to maintain.

Comment: Update your answer to add in those reasons - that way you keep it contextual and nothing is lost or overlooked in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-child()` pseudo class to specify which element in the group of siblings. [See :nth-child() Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```
.example1:nth-child(1) .special {
  color: green; font-weight:bold;
}
```

Alternatively there is the `:first-of-type` which will select the first element in the group. [See :first-of-type Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)

```
.example1:first-of-type .special {
  color: green; font-weight:bold;
}
```

Both selectors will achieve the same thing for you HTML snippet.